# Copy multiple ranges between workbooks using mapping table

Tags: vba, excel, range, mapping

I have a mapping table looking like this:

[image]

[Range mapping](https://habrastorage.org/webt/wa/jw/ha/wajwhablzjlh-kgepnka-fxjmq4.png)

What I need to do is:

1. Copy data from range E22:E59 of File 1, Sheet 1 to range G7:G42 of File 3, Sheet 1
2. Copy data from range E61:E69 of File 1, Sheet 1 to range G44:G52 of File 3, Sheet 1
3. Copy data from range E71:E74 of File 1, Sheet 1 to range G53:G56 of File 3, Sheet 1
4. Copy data from range G22:H69 of File 1, Sheet 2 to range H7:I52 of File 3, Sheet 2
5. ... etc. to the first empty line of mapping table

I'm trying this:

```
Sub Copy_Report_Data()

  Dim CurrentRow As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim Path As String
  Dim MacroWorkbook As Workbook
  Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook, SourceFileName As String, SourceTabName As String, SourceRangeFrom As String, SourceRangeTo As String, SourceRange As Range
  Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook, TargetFileName As String, TargetTabName As String, TargetRangeFrom As String, TargetRangeTo As String, TargetRange As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

  LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row

  For CurrentRow = 3 To LastRow

    If Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Value <> "" Then
      SourceTabName = Cells(CurrentRow, 2)
      TargetTabName = Cells(CurrentRow, 7)
    End If

    SourceRangeFrom = Cells(CurrentRow, 3)
    SourceRangeTo = Cells(CurrentRow, 4)

    TargetRangeFrom = Cells(CurrentRow, 8)
    TargetRangeTo = Cells(CurrentRow, 9)

    If Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value <> "" And CurrentRow <> 3 Then
      TargetWorkbook.Save
      TargetWorkbook.Close
      SourceWorkbook.Close
    End If

    If Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value <> "" Then
      SourceFileName = Cells(CurrentRow, 1)
      TargetFileName = Cells(CurrentRow, 6)
      Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Path & "Source\" & SourceFileName)
      Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Path & "Target\" & TargetFileName)
    End If

    SourceWorkbook.Sheets(SourceTabName).Range(SourceRangeFrom & ":" & SourceRangeTo).Copy
    TargetWorkbook.Sheets(TargetTabName).Range(TargetRangeFrom & ":" & TargetRangeTo).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    TargetWorkbook.Sheets(TargetTabName).Range(TargetRangeFrom & ":" & TargetRangeTo).Replace What:="x", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart

  Next CurrentRow

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

But I get runtime error on this row:

```
SourceWorkbook.Sheets(SourceTabName).Range(SourceRangeFrom & ":" & SourceRangeTo).Copy
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: When it errors what are the values of all the variables?  Do the make sense?

Comment: SourceRangeFrom and SourceRangeTo are empty. And looks like at the moment when error appears, the first line of mapping table is processed.

Comment: If I try step-by-step debugging (F8), everything is OK till first “workbook open” row, next F8 starts non-stoppable processing until the error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've used `Cells` in `If` conditions without specifying a workbook. As a result, values were taken from last opened workbook so variables became empty.

Here's a correct version with workbooks and sheets specified in `If` conditions:

```
Sub Copy_Report_Data()

  Dim CurrentRow As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim Path As String
  Dim MacroWorkbook As Workbook
  Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook, SourceFileName As String, SourceTabName As String, SourceRangeFrom As String, SourceRangeTo As String, SourceRange As Range
  Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook, TargetFileName As String, TargetTabName As String, TargetRangeFrom As String, TargetRangeTo As String, TargetRange As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set MacroWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

  Path = MacroWorkbook.Path & "\"
  LastRow = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row

  For CurrentRow = 3 To LastRow

    If MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Value <> "" Then
      SourceTabName = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 2)
      TargetTabName = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 7)
    End If

    SourceRangeFrom = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 3)
    SourceRangeTo = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 4)

    TargetRangeFrom = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 8)
    TargetRangeTo = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 9)

    If MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value <> "" And CurrentRow <> 3 Then
      TargetWorkbook.Save
      TargetWorkbook.Close
      SourceWorkbook.Close
    End If

    If MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value <> "" Then
      SourceFileName = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 1)
      TargetFileName = MacroWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Cells(CurrentRow, 6)
      Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Path & "Source\" & SourceFileName)
      Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Path & "Target\" & TargetFileName)
    End If

    'Debug.Print "Timestamp         "; Format(Now(), "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    'Debug.Print "CurrentRow        " & CurrentRow
    'Debug.Print "SourceWorkbook    " & "Source\" & SourceFileName
    'Debug.Print "SourceTabName     " & SourceTabName
    'Debug.Print "SourceRangeFrom   " & SourceRangeFrom
    'Debug.Print "SourceRangeTo     " & SourceRangeTo
    'Debug.Print "TargetWorkbook    " & "Target\" & TargetFileName
    'Debug.Print "TargetTabName     " & TargetTabName
    'Debug.Print "TargetRangeFrom   " & TargetRangeFrom
    'Debug.Print "---------------------------------------------------------"

    SourceWorkbook.Sheets(SourceTabName).Range(SourceRangeFrom & ":" & SourceRangeTo).Copy
    TargetWorkbook.Sheets(TargetTabName).Range(TargetRangeFrom).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    TargetWorkbook.Sheets(TargetTabName).Cells.Replace What:="x", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart

  Next CurrentRow

  TargetWorkbook.Save
  TargetWorkbook.Close
  SourceWorkbook.Close

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that `SourceRangeFrom` is supposed to be `E3` or anything like this, then simply write `debug.print SourceRangeFrom` before the error and see what is it. Do the same with `SourceRangeTo`. They should be some format, that is not an address.

Another option is simply to check for a NullString as probably some of the cells are empty. Thus after assigning the values write this:

```
If SourceRangeTo = vbNullString Or SourceRangeTo = vbNullString Or _
    TargetRangeFrom = vbNullString Or TargetRangeTo = vbNullString Then Stop
```

---

If you want the address of the `Cells(CurrentRow,3)` do the following:

In your code, instead of this:

```
SourceRangeFrom = Cells(CurrentRow, 3)
SourceRangeTo = Cells(CurrentRow, 4)
```

Assign like this:

```
SourceRangeFrom = Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Address
SourceRangeTo = Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Address
```

Otherwise you are getting the `Value` and not the `Address` of the Cell. Which is quite different.

Comment: the OP wants the value from the mapping table.  It contains a range reference.  It is this reference and not the address of the cell that the OP want to pass to the variable.